# Error on enabling CiviMobileAPI extension

Tags: extension

After installing the extension CiviMobileAPI, I am getting the below error when I access the contacts page. Can you please have a look and support.

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/hisadvocate/www/www/wp-content/extensions/com.agiliway.civimobileapi-3.1/com.agiliway.civimobileapi-3.1/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/ApiWrapper/Activity/Get.php on line 31

I am using the Civi CRM version 5.2.1. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a PR on the CiviMobileAPI that fixes this problem. See https://github.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/pull/11

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update, can you please advise how I can install this fix to my CiviCRM? I am not a programmer, just knows to setup wordpress and install the plugins/extensions

Comment: There are two options. Let me describe the first. The extension shows a warning. That is not an error. A warning is a signal to the programmer that the code must be improved, but the code still works. You can disable the warning. I asked Google  for advice and found the following link https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/disable-wordpress-php-error-messages/ .

Comment: The other option is to overwrite the file with the patch on the filesystem. The file can be downloaded here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/74922354f3b481b3a8e0ba0fecab57095a38842b/civimobileapi.php .

Comment: Thank you, I have copied this file and the warning disappeared!